# Derivation of an integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be an integrable function (not necessarily $\mathcal L^\infty$) on $[0, 1]$, and let's define $F(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt$.

$F$ is continuous because of continuity under integral sign (true?). Is $F$ differentiable and why?

EDIT : $F$ is not almost everywhere derivable but does $F$ belong to $H^1$? I expect this but I am not sure.

Comment: If you mean Lebesgue integrable, then $F$ is uniformly continuous and has a finite derivative almost everywhere.

Comment: is that true? uniform continuity implies differentiable a.e.?

Comment: Your second statement is not true. $F$ is differentiable a.e. because functions defined as integrals, as you have, are of finite variation. Functions of finite variation are differences of monotone functions. Monotone functions are differentiable a.e.. (There may be a quicker way to show this.)

Comment: Hmm if i take $f(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt(t)}$, i have $F(x) = \sqrt(x)$ which is not of finite variation in 0 i think.

Comment: Monotone functions are of finite variation ... ($f$ is of finite variation on $[0,1]$  means $\sup\{ \sum_{k=1}^ n |f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})| : 0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=1\}$ is finite.

Comment: oh I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F'$ exists and is $=f$ almost everywhere:
http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2010-11/2term/ma108b/10Ma108bdiffnotes.pdf, p. 107.

Answer (score 1):

F is not necessarily differentiable (at least in the usual sense), consider:

$f(t) = 0 $ for $t\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(t) = 1 $ for $t > \frac{1}{2}$.

Then

$F(x) = 0 $ for $x\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $F(x) = x - \frac{1}{2} $ for $x > \frac{1}{2}$.

and this is not differentiable at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: ok you are right. So i should change my question and ask whether F belongs to $H^1$ or not.